# add / remove class is not working for me in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Ok i have map area with image of circle and when i click a circle it rotate to right and show the content of that country, now this is working fine in safari and firefox but chrome is not responding, it doesn't remove the class and it doesnt add a new one to #circle, i need some help and explanation here.
I try to change removeClass to removeAttr but nothing, any other solution, thanks.

```js
$('.state').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#circle').removeClass('state1 state2 state3 state4 state5 rotate');
  $('#circle').addClass('state' + id);
  $('.stateDesc').hide(0);
  $('.state' + id).show('slow');
});
```

```css
img.state1,
img.state2,
img.state3,
img.state4,
img.state5 {
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease !important;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease !important;
  transition: all 1s ease !important;
}
img.state1 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
  transform: rotate(100deg) !important;
}
img.state2 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(195deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(195deg) !important;
  transform: rotate(205deg) !important;
}
img.state3 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(285deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(285deg) !important;
  transform: rotate(295deg) !important;
}
img.state4 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(145deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg) !important;
  transform: rotate(155deg) !important;
}
img.state5 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg) !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg) !important;
  transform: rotate(15deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="state" class="row stateRow">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-1 col-xs-3 circleCont hide">
    <img src="images/Circle_PRG_Web.png" alt="circle" id="circle" class="state1" usemap="#stateLinks" />
    <map id="states" name="stateLinks">
      <area class="state" data-id="1" shape="circle" coords="58,11,10" alt="Usa" title="USA">
      <area class="state" data-id="2" shape="circle" coords="30,98,10" alt="Canada" title="Canada">
      <area class="state" data-id="3" shape="circle" coords="104,132,10" alt="Mexico" title="Mexico">
      <area class="state" data-id="4" shape="circle" coords="13,48,10" alt="Japan" title="Japan">
      <area class="state" data-id="5" shape="circle" coords="134,53,10" alt="China" title="China">
    </map>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-6 stateBoth">
    <div class="stateLeft"></div>
    <div class="stateRight hide">
      <img src="images/dot.svg" alt="dot" class="stateDot dot" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="stateDesc state1"><span>USA</span>
      <p>Some dump text for usa ....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any errors in console? Have you tried logging if you are selecting elements?

Comment: Can you share s fiddle ?

Comment: You appear to have added a click listener to the `state` class however your code doesn't have any "state" classes?

Comment: @Justinas, no nothing in console.

Comment: @jamieBarker map area have state class

Comment: @Blackness Derp, I see it now. Could you update the snippet in your question with the relevant images?

Comment: Try removing just one class instead of `state1 state2 state3 state4 state5 rotate`, and see whether that works or no. It'll help you discover where the problem is.

Comment: @Blackness I would also point out that the code originally supplies was missing some closing `</div>` tags. I added them in based on the assumption they were missed with copy+paste, but if you don't have them then that may be why it's not working in some browsers.

Comment: @ag_dhruv yes I already try that, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem, I was using jQuery plugin qTip2 and when I remove this code bellow it works great, but now i nead to fix qTip2 code so I can get my tooltip.

```
$('area').qtip({
    content: {
        text: $('map').attr("title")
    },
    position: {
        target: 'mouse'
    },
    style: { classes: 'myTooltip' }
});
```

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

I add `z-index: -1 !important;` 
to `.myTooltip` and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : put your script inside `$(document).ready...` which will ensure that your DOM is ready and then script will get applied, see below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.state').click(function() {
       var id = $(this).data('id');
       $( '#circle' ).removeClass('state1 state2 state3 state4 state5 rotate');
       $('#circle').addClass('state'+id);
       $('.stateDesc').hide(0);
       $('.state'+id).show('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: It is inside the $(document).ready(function() { }, thanks for effort